# X.509 and Private Key Confusion

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, certificate, x509certificate

I have been given a x.509 certifcate and a private key.

The certificate looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICdzCCAeCgAwIBAgIGAOH4vsPYMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMFMxCzAJBgNVBAYT
AlVTMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpBbWF6b24uY29tMQwwCgYDVQQLEwNBV1MxITAfBgNVBAMT
GEFXUyBMaW1pdGVkLUFzc3VyYW5jZSBDQTAeFw0wODEwMzExMjQyNDBaFw0wOTEw
MzExMjQyNDBaMFIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpBbWF6b24uY29tMRcw
LOTS OF LETTERS
SO MANY LETTERS
r8AmrDQ9VfrocQIDAQABo1cwVTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwFgYDVR0lAQH/BAww
K9gtkPlKRDCaBDQ2xukycq4bv+EhEQPzPY+VeWGYzizl91K8knpI3VLLiJD0CNkb
UvSoj/wZv0zWf13oMgMyUbrFygpHVmA2uYwi6kFKXy/D2vGXUsrEgFqP6xFvgUA3
JDIblstGT383+IY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and the private key looks like

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Lots of letters here as well
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I believe I need this certificate because I must use a plugin called *Elastic Fox* in order to properly connect to our AWS account. I am confused on how to add this certificate to firefox / how to use the certificate and private key.

I attempted to save both the certificate and private key in one .pem file and import that to FF via: `Edit > Preferences > Advanced > View Certificates > Your Certificates > Import`, but I was told to enter some password that I do not know/have:

[image]

I attempted to save just the private key portion as a .key file in ~/.ssh/id_rsa , but that did not work.

Can someone ELI5 to me how to add this certificate properly and what to do with the private key? Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: To get you started, what you showed is PEM encoded. In OpenSSL, you would specify it with `-inform PEM`. I don't know what you AWS account needs, so I don't know what you should use for `-outform`. Precisely what form do you need?

Comment: What do you mean what the account needs?

Comment: @noloader I tried uploading my file with the extension .pem like the picture here: http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/ The file contained the private key info and the certificate.

Comment: A couple of things.  First it would appear that Elastic Fox allows you to use an AWS access key.  In the AWS console, you can go to IAM, and pick the account you want to log in as.  Get the AWS Access Key and Secret and paste them into the box described in the Elastic Fox documentation page 11.

Comment: You can use certificates to access AWS, but you have to upload the certificates to a particular IAM user in the IAM console.  There are at least two other places certificates are used, one is the certificate that is installed as part of the server startup.  That allows you to ssh to the server after a new Instance is brought up.  When you create an instance it will ask you which certificate to use.  It will install that cert (not really a cert but a public/private key), then you can use your local version of that key to ssh in to the new instance.

Comment: There is also another place you can upload certs that are used for load balancers.  Anyway, check out IAM in your AWS console and plug your access keys into FE from there.

Comment: As a final note, if you want to use a cert for AWS access, it wasn't clear from the EF doc that is support User certs for access.  Here is a link that explains how to generate the certs for AWS access.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingUserCerts.html#Using_UploadCertificate

Comment: If you've been 'given a private key' there is already a major security problem here, because the 'private key' isn't private at all. It's known to at least two people. It doesn't uniquely identify you. The guy who gave it to you can also use it.

Comment: @EJP I thought the private key and certifiate was needed to make the x.509 certificate.

Comment: Of course a private key is needed. I haven't said otherwise. But you should have generated the private key yourself, not been given it.

Comment: @EJP I ended up creating a whole different user with newly generated private key and certificate. From there, I gave the user full privs. Thank you for the information.